# Get consecutive subarray size with largest size

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers, now I want to find all the consecutive subarray sums whose value matches with less than or equal to k. I want to return the largest subarray size.

This is my program:

```
public static int process(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            sum += arr.get(j);
            if (sum <= k) {
                size = Math.max(size, j - i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

**constraints:**

```
arr size is between 1 to 100000
array elements are between 1 to 100
k is between 1 to 1000000
```

**Explanation:**

```
Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1), 7

arr = 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1

k= 7
```

possible sub arrays:

```
[2], [3], [5], [1], [1], [2], [1]

[2,3], [5,1], [1,1], [1,2], [2,1]

[5,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,1]

[1,1,2,1]

Maximum sub array is [1,1,2,1] = its length is 4. So program should return 4.
```

I got this task in a competitive exam last week, when I used this code it has passed only 50% test cases. It failed for some hidden test cases saying wrong output, and some test cases saying time out.

What is the issue with my code?

**Update:**
Modified my code little bit. And added a sample example.

Comment: Can u explain ur question and desired output a little more

Comment: Are you supposed to return 0 when none of the subarrays add to `k`?

Comment: @Hades, sorry I missed to add them let me modiy the question again

Comment: The reason for the timeout is that your algorithm is O(n^2). You could speed it up a little bit by breaking the inner loop as soon as the sum is greater than `k`. You could speed it up a lot by using a sliding window.

Comment: Probably, your issue is that you keep going when `sum > k`. Or, at least, part of it. You should only look ahead from `i` until the cumulative sum from there exceeds the sum you were aiming for.

Comment: @user3386109, sorry I missed to add that value should be <= k. Updated my post and code little bit.

Comment: Since the array elements are all positive numbers, you still want to `break` the inner loop when `sum > k`. And a sliding window is still the fastest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops means that performance is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. You need to re-think the algorithm.

Below is an *O(n)* solution, which I will show by example. Writing the code is still your challenge.

What we need is a way to know the sum of values *before* a particular index. With that we can calculate `sumRange(i, j) = sumBefore(j) - sumBefore(i)`.

Since we're looking for `sumRange(i, j) = k`, we need to check if we have a `sumBefore(i) = sumBefore(j) - k`. If we do, we have a candidate range with `size = j - i`.

So, iterate the values and calculate the accumulated sum. Build a `Map` of `accSum` to `indexAfter` the value leading to that accumulated sum.

Say the array is `[1, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 4, 2, 7, 1]` and `k = 13`:

```java
Index:          0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Value:          1   6   5   3   2   8   4   2   7   1
accSum:     0   1   7  12  15  17  25  29  31  38  39   sumBefore
            ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓
indexAfter: 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   index
```

Adding the dummy `0 → 0` mapping just simplifies the logic of your code.

As you iterate, you have the accumulated sum up to now, inclusive, i.e. `sumBefore(i + 1)`, so look to see if we have a range, i.e. `sumBefore(x) = sumBefore(i + 1) - k = accSum - k`, so look in the map for `accSum - k`, and if found, the value is `x`, meaning we have a candidate range of `x, i+1`.

I hope that all made sense.

---

**UPDATE**

The question was changed to look for sums `<= k`, not just sums exactly equal to `k`.

This is easily done with the logic above by changing the `Map` to a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), or more specifically a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), and replace the [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) call with a [`ceilingEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#ceilingEntry-K-) call:

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the **least key greater than or equal** to the given key, or `null` if there is no such key.

If the returned key (sum) is greater than the parameter, the result is a subarray sum that is less than `k`.